# Does the field (force-carrying) of a gluon or boson have a magnetic-like shape? Not spherical

Tags: magnetic-fields, weak-interaction, bosons, gluons

The challenge of force-carrying boson is that many experiments generate results that are not consistent.  Hence, quantum statistics.

It is established that things like 'strong nuclear interaction/force' have a narrow range.

https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=ebnYHZD%2b&id=C22C7DB427700E7BFDA20CE624D109B5FDFD67BE&thid=OIP.ebnYHZD-9HtXSbnpmHYXpgAAAA&mediaurl=https%3a%2f%2fqph.ec.quoracdn.net%2fmain-qimg-51af644351186cffd0775c7dfb710213-c&exph=256&expw=474&q=weak+interaction+graph&simid=608021531313638381&selectedIndex=1&ajaxhist=0

I have compared the experimental evidence above for strong force, and found that results very similar to a f(x) = 1/x^3 - 1/x^2 - 1/((x-1)^2+1) where x = distance between nucleons given a non-charge neutron remains in between.  The -1/x^2 matches to Coulomb's electrostatic replusion, which leaves a 1/x^3 factors attractions which matches magnetics fields decrease rate.  Therefore, that leads me to believe that the 'elementary particles' express in 1/x^3 which would lead me to consider their field magnetic-like.

Any ideas how I can further test this postulate?

Comment: Welcome. [About the distribution of the electrons magnetic dipole moments in atoms](https://www.academia.edu/18391675/About_the_distribution_of_electrons_magnetic_dipole_moments_in_atoms_Octahedral_model_)

Comment: That is part 2, if the elementary particles have something magnetic-like, then when you put another atom.  This takes the UIowa work on water (H2O) another step (Kemp, Gordon) or see Bieze, van der Maarel - 1993).  I don't like the direction they take.  Instead, if you bring an electron close (in the hydrogen bond of H2O liquid) that has a subatomic nucleomagnetics field, then the settling position of the first H2O can change by that magnetic field.  It rotates which increase the strength, moves the settling position of its Hydrogen which changes the dipole distance - thus your answer.

Comment: It can change the 1.85 D to 2.8 for water!  That is exactly the work I am doing.  Huge recalculation that gets a dipole with only one bond, not the many of Kemp, etc.

Comment: Your paper is on point!  However, consider adding my nucleomagnetics is two (2) hemispheres . . . therefore, 2 x N^2 is the shell size, and take your model to full geometry with nucleomagnetics creating the balancing force.